# saving unstructured data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am able to save request the data if I explicitly define in my express model the structure, but I am not able to save record if I do not explicitly define the data structure.

For example I am able to save if I have this in my model

```
....
module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    admin: Boolean
}));
...
...
```

but I am not able to save it if I have it like this

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', new Schema());
```

Here is my model

```
// get an instance of mongoose and mongoose.Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports
module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', new Schema());
```

And here is my Router

```
apiRouter.post('/forms/createForm', function(req, res) {

    var form = new Form(req.body);

    form.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Form saved successfully');
        res.json({ success: true });
    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok I got that working.

There is a strict false option that I can use to define the schemaless structure.

Thats how I did it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports

module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', new Schema({}, { strict: false} ));
```